# JSS security over http tunneling

Tags: rmi, nss, http-tunneling

I have a mozila.jss ssl socket and I'm using it for RMI connection.
I'm trying to convert the RMI connection to RMI-over-http connection using apache server with tomcat.
For the RMI-over-http I'm using RMIHttpsToCGISocketFactory.
The question is how can I use the JSS authentication (FIPS compatible) over HTTP.

I would appreciate any input on this subject

Thanks